# How to get the driving distance between two geographical coordinates using python?

Tags: python, geospatial, openstreetmap, driving-distance

I want to get the driving distance between two points in python. I am not allowed to use Google Maps API. Are there any open source APIs that help to calculate the driving distance between two points? If yes, a small example is Python will be amazing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing#End_users:_Routing_software

Answer (score 17):

Example from the python package OSMNX:

[example doc](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/00-osmnx-features-demo.ipynb) -> routing

```
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox

# get the nearest network node to each point
orig_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, (37.828903, -122.245846))
dest_node = ox.get_nearest_node(G, (37.812303, -122.215006))

# how long is our route in meters?
nx.shortest_path_length(G, orig_node, dest_node, weight='length')
```

Documentation on how to install: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation

Note the following excerpt:

'*If you are pip installing OSMnx, install geopandas and rtree first. It’s easiest to use conda-forge to get these dependencies installed.*'

Comment: you need to add this line to answer `G = ox.graph_from_place("ADDRESS", network_type="drive")`